# How to call a contract function from a specific address

Tags: node.js, ethereum, solidity

I want to use web3 to call a contract function(sendTransaction not call) from a specific address that I hold the private key to. I also have the contract instance connected. I know I have to dio something like web3.personal.unlockAccount(address,password,duration)
And then specify the from address. 
So my question is, is "password" where I enter my private key? And how do I pass that address into fromAddress once I unlock it. 
Or is there a more streamlined way to go about it?

Answer (score 2):

> is "password" where I enter my private key?

**No**, it's not. Actually it is a password, which you entered when you were creating account and which was used to generate your keystore file.

---

If you use `web3.personal.unlockAccount(address,password,duration)` you need to have your keystore file in the `keystore` folder near chaindata of geth.

---

Another way will be to use [`web3.eth.sendRawTransaction`](http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.eth.html?#web3.eth.Eth.sendRawTransaction) from `web3.py`, but it will be a little bit clunky to call contract method from it.

```
key = '0x' + 'YOUR-PRIVATE-KEY
transaction = {
    'to': _to,
    'value': 0,
    'gas': 300000,
    'gasPrice': 23000000000,
    'nonce': web3.eth.getTransactionCount(_from),
    'chainId': int(web3.admin.nodeInfo['protocols']['eth']['network']),
    'data': b''
}

signed = web3.eth.account.signTransaction(transaction, key)
print("Transaction Hash: " + web3.toHex(web3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed.rawTransaction)))
```

---

My suggestion will be to create keyfile recognisable by Ethereum clients by using [`web3.eth.account.encrypt`](http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/web3.eth.account.html#web3.account.Account.encrypt) (`web3.py` because `web3.js` yet lack this functionality) and after you generate it put it in the right folder and try simply to unlock account.